# Converting an Nsmutable array into Mkannotation array

Tags: objective-c, core-data, maps, mkannotation

Hello all I was playing with core-data ....I have an entity which contains latitude longitude and some description information now for this entity i created an Nsmanaged object class and then assigned in property tag.

Now i have successfully parsed an XML put them into core-data and drill downed the data from core-data into Nsmuatble array now array has some objects in it and i cannot add the objects to map (i know the reason why it does not add,coz the array is not type of mkannotation ).

Now is there any chance i can create a entity which is a class of mk annotation .Or else i will create a one more Mkannotation object class and pass down the data and convert it into mk annotation class

Answer (score 0):

Your custom managed subclass needs to implement the [MKAnnotationProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) which is not the same thing as being an MKAnnotation object.

You need to declare that it conforms to the protocol with a `<MKAnnotation>` in the class interface declaration, and then you need to provide an implementation of the `coordinate` property to return a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from the properties of your object.

Comment: I have Created an object class of type mkannotation and then referenced that class to an entity and while i was parsing i was just inserting into Entity and using them in my projec